# Сохранение "зебры" в CSS при вставке инородного элемента

Tags: css

Есть полосатый список, раскрашиваемый за счет селектора nth-child.

Как вставить в список "инородный объект" так, чтобы раскраска основных элементов не изменялась, в какую бы позицию мы не вставили чужака? Пусть инородность будет отмечена специальным классом.

Желаемый результат:
[image: zebra]

С помощью jQuery я добиваюсь желаемого так:

```js
$('li:not(.spacer):even').css('background', 'cyan')
```

```css
li { 
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    background: yellow;
}
li.spacer {
    background: silver;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>item #1</li>
    <li class="spacer">spacer</li>
    <li>item #2</li>
    <li>item #3</li>
    <li>item #4</li>
    <li>item #5</li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qznv3fed/

Это НЕ эквивалентно селектору `li:not(.spacer):nth-child(even)` в CSS или в том же jQuery!
nth-child() принимает в расчет "инородный элемент" тоже, а я пытаюсь этого избежать.

**UPDATE:**
Видимо стоит пояснить:

- верстка должна оставаться валидной
- банальности c доп. разметкой классами .even и .odd или inline-стилями неинтересны
- решение на JS уже есть, давайте поищем CSS

Comment: на чистом css не получится. единственный вариант вставлять элемент другого типа, что-то вроде: http://jsfiddle.net/qznv3fed/1/

Comment: как простой вариант - можно просто на элементы классы нацепить для четного-нечетного и в них цвет выставлять

Comment: @Grundy Рекомендую оформить это в виде ответа

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо, но вопрос поставлен именно так. Ищу решение на CSS без доп. разметки.

Comment: @tutankhamun, такой ответ не будет принят :) Варианты: забить, сделать таки на JS, оформить полосатость классами или инлайн стилями — очевидны и не интересны.

Comment: Сделать инородный элемент - элементом другого типа - на мой взгляд, самый подходящий вариант. Именно этот комментарий я рекомендовал оформить в виде ответа. Вопрос валидности - это глупость стандарта HTML. Яндекс.Карты вставляют элементы `ymaps` и никто им не предъявляет претензии.

Comment: Невалидная разметка приводит к непредсказуемым результатам. Вы же не вставляете щелочные батарейки в зарядник для Ni-Cd аккумуляторов!

Comment: @tutankhamun, этот вариант есть у меня в ответе, кроме того если вместо списка использовать те же дивы, а для разделителя, например, `span` с `display:block` - то разметка будет валидна

Comment: @Grundy если бы вы дали такой вариант  — с валидными разными тегами — и я плюсану его. А вкорячивать div посреди li это бардак.

Comment: @artoodetoo, добавил вариант без списка.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С помощью одного CSS это сделать нельзя.

Самое простое решение в лоб: при построении страницы, указать конкретным элементам списка четные они или нет с помощью классов. В таком случае проблема решится сама собой.

```css
li { 
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    background: yellow;
}
li.even{
  background: cyan;
}
li.spacer {
    background: silver;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="odd">item #1</li>
    <li class="spacer">spacer</li>
    <li class="even">item #2</li>
    <li class="odd">item #3</li>
    <li  class="even">item #4</li>
    <li class="odd">item #5</li>
</ul>
```

Следующий вариант: вставлять элемент другого типа и использовать селектор [`:nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-of-type)

```css
li { 
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    background: yellow;
}

li:nth-of-type(even) {
    background: cyan;
}
.spacer {
    background: silver;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>item #1</li>
    <div class="spacer">spacer</div>
    <li>item #2</li>
    <li>item #3</li>
    <li>item #4</li>
    <li>item #5</li>
</ul>
```

Без списка

```css
div { 
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    background: yellow;
}

div:nth-of-type(even) {
    background: cyan;
}
span.spacer {
    background: silver;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div>item #1</div>
    <span class="spacer">spacer</span>
    <div>item #2</div>
    <div>item #3</div>
    <div>item #4</div>
    <div>item #5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы не послушались комментария! Сами понимаете, разметить каждую полоску классом я мог и не задавая вопроса на SO. Как и отказаться от идеи вообще. Ответ не принимается.

Comment: @artoodetoo, а второй вариант вы рассматривали? или только первый пример?

Comment: Второй вариант невалиден.

Comment: @artoodetoo, только для списка. Ну и кстати - основной ответ-то: в данный момент с CSS это сделать нельзя - прям первая строчка

Comment: div + span это хоть неэлегантное, но решение :) +1

Comment: @artoodetoo, там _span_

Comment: Опечатка, сорри

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32359/discussion-between-grundy-and-artoodetoo).

Answer (score 0):

вот еще такой вариант

```css
body{
  background: #fff;
}

ul {
    width: 100%;        
    margin: 25px auto;
    text-align: center;
}
li{
    padding: 5px;
}
.spacer{
  background: #ccc;
}
.item,
.item ~ .item ~ .item,
.item ~ .item ~ .item ~ .item ~ .item,
.item ~ .item ~ .item ~ .item ~ .item ~ .item ~ .item,
.item ~ .item ~ .item ~ .item ~ .item ~ .item ~ .item ~ .item ~ .item{
    background: #01FFFF;
}

.item ~ .item,
.item ~ .item ~ .item ~ .item,
.item ~ .item ~ .item ~ .item ~ .item ~ .item,
.item ~ .item ~ .item ~ .item ~ .item ~ .item ~ .item ~ .item,
.item ~ .item ~ .item ~ .item ~ .item ~ .item ~ .item ~ .item ~ .item ~ .item{
    background-color: #FFFF00;
}
```

```html
<ul>    
    <li class="item">item #1</li>
    <li class="spacer">spacer</li>
    <li class="item">item #2</li>
    <li class="item">item #3</li>
    <li class="item">item #4</li>
    <li class="item">item #5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: если уберете последние 4 правила - ничего не поменяется :-)

Comment: Не очень понятно как это вообще работает, но путем перестановки "спейсеров" я могу получить то правильную зебру, то полоски одного цвета. Сравните: http://jsfiddle.net/qznv3fed/2/ и http://jsfiddle.net/qznv3fed/3/ . Незачет!